# Full replication of Capped Collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, replication, database, nosql

Can I setup capped collection on machine A and non-capped replication of that collection on machine B (so that machine B has all the data that was written on machine A)?

**The reason behind:**
The data on machine A fills in very quickly (over 10GB per day) and I want to make sure that this data does not exhausts the disk space and brings down the whole server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was recently asked and answered on the MongoDB Users list so I'll just link to the answer [there](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/6NDCKa4sp1E/discussion) but for locality, I'll summarize:

"No, there is no option for that. The goal of replication it have the *same* data on all nodes."

The answer there also includes a possible way to do this, but it would be completely unsupported (and unadvised).

Comment: Thanks for the link and for others who are also interested in this, the thread that Asya linked provides an easy way to achieve this setup.